# Undeploy application by recipe

Tags: cloudify

I'm using Cloudify 2.7 with OpenStack Icehouse.

I would like to exit from the deploy process of a service if a condition happens in the `-service.groovy` file.

Can someone suggest to me how should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish.

If you just want the instance to stop processing further lifecycle events, have you script exit with a non-zero exit code and use the 'disableSelfHealing' flag when you install the service (http://getcloudify.org/guide/2.7/deploying/deploying_srvs.html)

If you want to actually uninstall the service, you need to use the REST API (or the provided rest-client package - https://github.com/CloudifySource/cloudify/tree/master/rest-client) to uninstall the service.

Comment: I added the following:

def process = ["bash", "-c", "curl -X DELETE http://<CFY_MANAGER_IP>:8100/2.7.1/deployments/$applicationName"].execute();

in the "detail" section of "-service.groovy" file.

Comment: To retrieve the Cloudify Manager IP: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31607837/retrieve-ip-of-the-cloudify-manager-from-inside-cloudify-application-vm/31634497#31634497