# Retrieve IP of the Cloudify Manager from inside Cloudify Application VM

Tags: cloudify

I am using Cloudify 2.7 with OpenStack Iceouse.

How could I do to retrieve IP of the Cloudify Manager from inside Cloudify Application VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. Unfortunately, there is no simple API to get this. As Cloudify 2 has reached End-of-Life, there are no plans for adding such an API.

Having said that, there is an environment variable that contains this information. The environment variable name is:

```
LOOKUPLOCATORS
```

The value of this variable is of the format:

```
<HOST1>:<PORT1>;<HOST2>:<PORT2>
```

Where each of the hosts is a cloudify 2 manager.

Comment: Following a simple code to extract the IP of one CFY Manager:

def lookuplocator = System.getenv()["LOOKUPLOCATORS"]
String cfyMngtIp = lookuplocator.substring(0, lookuplocator.indexOf(':'))